Proper exterior outlet (non-surface mount)
I have the following boxes on my exterior wall:

It’s a normal 1gang ENT box with an extension ring. The extension ring screws onto the actual box with a long #6 screw.
I got the following outdoor receptacle cover:


Is this the right way to do it and the right box? Does anything look fishy?

Currently I used the same screw to first get though the exterior box, then the receptacle, then the extension ring and finally the buried ENT box. Is the better choice to first fix the receptacle only and then use small screws to screw the exterior outlet cover to the receptacle?
The box is not completely flush with the wall. Should I caulk around it?
The wall will still be painted. Is it better to first paint and then (re)install the outlet ?


Well, you really have more than one question here.  But:
It looks about right.  For some reason your cover looks really old though.
With your extension I think you're stuck with the long screw.
As long as the foam gasket has some squish to it, I don't think there's any need to caulk.
As far as paint, it's your choice.  If you care about paint getting on the box, but are confident you can avoid it, you can leave it.  If you aren't confident, remove the box and outlet, paint, and replace.  If you don't care, leave it and just slather the paint.

Thanks. I feel there is so little information about exterior boxes (that are not surface mount) and the shown one is technically meant to be installed on a box, I believe? Hence my hesitation. Good to hear that it looks fine!

The box I reused. It’s only 1-2 years old though. I have another new one though

Re gasket/caulk: As I said, I feel it doesn’t squish/seal super well. Also stucco wall is rough. Does it harm to just caulk well around it? Re paint, I think I would just tape it while painting.

If you're worried about the foam, you could get some closed cell foam and add a little thickness in an upside-down U shape.
